# Dynamics Ax 2012 Bring all Record except 1

Tags: filter, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I made a new form and add grid. Add Datasource to grid to show records but I want to show all records without Enum::No so (All Records - Enum Value No One)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need overwrite the `init` **method** of your datasource and add this

Option 1

```
this.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(YourDataSource)).addRange(fieldnum(YourDataSource, YourField)).value(strfmt('!%1',enum2str(YourEnum::YourOption)));
```

Option 2

```
this.query().dataSourceTable(tablenum(YourTable)).addRange(fieldnum(YourTable, YourField)).value(enum2Str(Enum::Yes));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in the **init** method of Form

```
MYTABLE_ds.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(MYTABLE)).addRange(fieldNum(MYTABLE,MYFİELD)).value(strFmt("!%1",enum2str(ENUM::No)));
```

This solution worked too

Comment: You need overwirte init method of datasource, not init method of form.